# User should not be able to select past month/year as expiry date

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

Hi am using [SRmonthpicker](https://github.com/simonrice/SRMonthPicker) for selection of date as per my requirement. I want to disable previous month/year selection. i.e if current month is june then previous months shold be disabled

[image]
Please Help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't look like you can.  You can specify the minimum year, but not the minimum month/year.  Even the delegate methods don't provide the ability to reject changes (return type is `void` and not `BOOL`).  You'll have to modify the class yourself (and send a pull request to the author) or use a better designed control.

Comment: Set the mininum date for datepicker as current date ...please give it a try for this code....[picker setMinimumDate: [NSDate date]];

Comment: @trojanfoe do you have any ref control for this ?

Comment: @trojanfoe can you help me with this SRmonthpicker ? –

Comment: @ trojanfoe....have u tried to set the current date as a set minimum date to date picker method